# Drupal 8 Bootstrap Theme Dropdown on Hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal-8

I am working on creating a custom bootstrap theme for Drupal 8 and my goal is to have the main nav menu dropdown child items on hover instead of making the user click, I have found a few suggestions like adding this to my CSS in my theme:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
}
```

And this to my themes .info file:

```
function YOURTHEME_menu_link(array $variables) {
$element = $variables['element'];
$sub_menu = '';

if ($element['#below']) {
// Prevent dropdown functions from being added to management menu so it
// does not affect the navbar module.
if (($element['#original_link']['menu_name'] == 'management') && (module_exists('navbar'))) {
  $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
}
else if ((!empty($element['#original_link']['depth'])) && ($element['#original_link']['depth'] == 1)) {
  // Add our own wrapper.
  unset($element['#below']['#theme_wrappers']);
  $sub_menu = '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' . drupal_render($element['#below']) . '</ul>';
  // Generate as standard dropdown.
  $element['#title'] .= ' <span class="caret"></span>';
  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'dropdown';
  $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;

  // Set dropdown trigger element to # to prevent inadvertant page loading
  // when a submenu link is clicked.
  //$element['#localized_options']['attributes']['data-target'] = '#';
  $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'dropdown-toggle';
  //$element['#localized_options']['attributes']['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
}
}

// On primary navigation menu, class 'active' is not set on active menu  item.
// @see https://drupal.org/node/1896674
if (($element['#href'] == $_GET['q'] || ($element['#href'] == '<front>' && drupal_is_front_page())) && (empty($element['#localized_options']['language']))) {
$element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'active';
}

$output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'],    $element['#localized_options']);
   return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' .                                                   $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

But this had no effect on my theme and I still need to click for the dropdown.

Comment: Btw. You should use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot()` instead of deprecated `drupal_render()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the Bootstrap dropdown menu works to the click event. You need to write hover function with jquery.

That's how I solved:

```
$(".nav li.expanded").hover(
    function(){
      $(this).addClass("open");
    },function(){
      $(this).removeClass("open");
    }
  );
```

I add the open, or remove the class, which add by click function in Bootstrap. So this will opens the menu.

Answer (score 5):

This can also be achieved using CSS only, use below CSS to open submenu on hover,

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated for Bootstrap4 Theme for Durpal:

```
$(".navbar-nav .dropdown").hover(
function(){
  $(this).addClass("show");
  $("ul.dropdown-menu", this).addClass("show");
},function(){
  $(this).removeClass("show");
  $("ul.dropdown-menu", this).removeClass("show");
});
```

Comment: This does not provide a clear answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Comment: It's working but has issue when we have more than 1 step dropdown. When we hover the 1st level the 2nd and 3rd levels also become visible.